# Faster processing of SendARP function

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, synchronization, arp

Originally posted here, but found off topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/617459/faster-processing-of-sendarp-function

I've been working on a network scanner for Windows. I have successfully written the code, but the problem is it takes too much time to scan the hosts that aren't up. When I tried scanning a subnet (1 to 255), it took more than half hour. I couldn't find a function to control the time limit or a way to control the time-out of SendARP function.

```
    DestIp = inet_addr(strn.c_str());                   //Setting Destination IPv4       dotted-decimal address into a proper address for the IN_ADDR structure.
    SrcIp = inet_addr(SrcIpString);

    memset(&MacAddr, 0xff, sizeof(MacAddr));                     //Initializing MAC Address to ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff

    dwRetVal = SendARP(DestIp, SrcIp, &MacAddr, &PhysAddrLen);                    //Sending ARP request to the destined IP Address

    if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) {
        bPhysAddr = (BYTE *)& MacAddr;
        if (PhysAddrLen) {
            std::cout << strn<<std::endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)PhysAddrLen; i++) {
                if (i == ((int)PhysAddrLen - 1))
                    printf("%.2X\n", (int)bPhysAddr[i]);
                else
                    printf("%.2X-", (int)bPhysAddr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `SendARP()` using multiple threads so you can query more than one address in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a convenience function from the "IP Helper" library. That's not performance-oriented.

The ServerFault comments actually hit the mail on the head: use threads. With `<thread>` that's nowadays quite simple. Just do 255 `std::async` calls to your function. Of course, make sure that all the `MacAddr` and `PhysAddrLen` references aren't invalidated.